# How to edit jquery.min.js

Tags: jquery, html, web

I am learner. I have a jquery.min.js file.I want to edit that .But that's looks so horrible(as all codes are in 1 line).

So please help me to edit that file.

Thank You...

Comment: If you don't already know how to edit the jQuery core, you probably shouldn't.

Comment: that's why I m asking ...

Comment: I said, you probably shouldn't. If you want to see how specific functions are written, take a look at this [jQuery source viewer](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/). However, if you're new to JavaScript, you probably won't make heads or tails of any of it, and you certainly shouldn't be modifying it unless you're sure of what you're doing.

Comment: Unless you are working on developing the jQuery library itself, you should not be editing the jQuery file. Period.

Answer (score 3):

The 'min' part of jquery.min.js means that the file is [minified](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_%28programming%29).  This is **not** a developer version or one to play around in, this is a production copy.  If you would like to see more under the hood stuff take a look at the [github](https://github.com/jquery/jquery).